# How to make cross domain Ajax request from cached static html file in hybrid app?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, hybrid

For some reason we are building a hybrid app, cache html ,JavaScript and css as static files in the app. But there is a problem: the web-view loads the html via file://,  it cannot make Ajax call to the server because cross domain problem, the origin domain in header is null.

For secure reason we do not want to set allowed origin to * on server side.
How to resolve this?

Any suggestions will be appropriated.

Comment: my eyes bled reading this question. Anyway you can make a `HTTP` request to a file in order to `GET` information, you just need a server running or wamp.

Comment: We do have a server. The problem is how to make Ajax request from static html file in an app container?

Comment: Use `jQuery`, `AngularJS`, `ReactJS` or whatever other framework you want to make the **GET** request. [jQuery example](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp)